# One ggplot with multiple data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I try to place points on a map so I am using `ggmap`. For the points, I have two separate data sets and the sample is below.

```
dta1 = data.frame(storename = c(letters[1:5]),
                      storesize = c("small","small","medium","large","large"),
                      lon = c(10,11.2,15,19,22),
                      lat = c(5,5.8,5.6,6.1,3.4))
    dta2 = data.frame(population = sample(100,100,replace = T),
                      lon = runif(100,10,22),
                      lat = runif(100,3.5,6))
```

Here is the sample code for the plot. In my real data set, I have `ggmap(map)` instead of `ggplot()`. Why below code does not work?

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=dta1,
                      aes(x=lon, y=lat,size = storesize), shape = 23,fill="blue") + 
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1,2,3)) +
  geom_point(data=dta2,
             aes(x=lon, y=lat,size = population), shape = 21,fill="orange")
```

If I run those separately like this, it works

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=dta1,
                      aes(x=lon, y=lat,size = storesize), shape = 23,fill="blue") + 
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1,2,3))

ggplot() +  geom_point(data=dta2,
             aes(x=lon, y=lat,size = population), shape = 21,fill="orange")
```

I would like to have one plot with two separate legends as each separated plot shows.

In addition, if I need to point one more particular place with a different shape (let's say `shape = 11`), how should I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is described [here](https://eliocamp.github.io/codigo-r/2018/09/multiple-color-and-fill-scales-with-ggplot2/) and [here](https://gist.github.com/eliocamp/eabafab2825779b88905954d84c82b32).
Install `ggnewscale` and then add a new scale using `new_scale`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

dta1 = data.frame(storename = c(letters[1:5]),
                      storesize = c("small","small","medium","large","large"),
                      lon = c(10,11.2,15,19,22),
                      lat = c(5,5.8,5.6,6.1,3.4))
dta2 = data.frame(population = sample(100,100,replace = T),
                      lon = runif(100,10,22),
                      lat = runif(100,3.5,6))

ggplot() + 
geom_point(data=dta1,  aes(x=lon, y=lat,size=storesize), shape=23, fill="blue") + 
scale_size_manual(values = c(1,2,3)) +
new_scale("size") +
geom_point(data=dta2, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=population), shape=21, fill="orange")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, with my actual codes, there is an error.

Comment: p1 + geom_point(data=TongBan0,
                aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size = `Num of HH per Census Block`),colour="chocolate")  +
  new_scale("size") +  
  geom_point(data=pred_daily_Sales3,
             aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size = `Potential Store`), shape = 23,fill="blue") +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(5,6,7)) + 
  new_scale("size") +
  geom_point(data=Stores_Suwon[Stores_Suwon$Suwon_Store_id > 6,],
                   aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size = `Incumbent Stores`),shape = 25, fill = "green")   +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(7,6,5))

Comment: If I run above, I got, "Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'guide_none' of mode 'function' was not found "

Comment: Yes. With only two like this <br> p1 + geom_point(data=TongBan0, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size = Num of HH per Census Block),colour="chocolate") + new_scale("size") + geom_point(data=pred_daily_Sales3, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, size = Potential Store), shape = 23,fill="blue") + scale_size_manual(values = c(5,6,7)) <br> I got the same error

Comment: Sorry for the messy. I don't know how to make codes with the code format. control + k does not work

Comment: I install the pacakge, "ggnewscale" and it works. Thank you so much